# How do I make my blog iPad / iPhone / Android friendly?

Tags: mobile, iphone, android

How do I make sure my blog is iPad / iPhone / Android / touch-device friendly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use the [WP Touch plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) on my site.  It automatically detects if the user is browsing with an iPhone (or iPad) and reformats the site into an iOS-friendly layout with touch-sensitive controls.  There's an option at the bottom for visitors to display the normal site if they want.

It's a very well-supported system, and I've used it on 3 of my own sites and 12 client sites so far without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: This also seems to work great for Android devices, in my (limited) experience.

Comment: It also seems to work fairly well on Blackberry devices ... at least it does on the Storm, not sure about the non-touch screen Blackberries ...

Comment: WordPress.com also use WPtouch. wp-super cache will work well with it - it caches on a per- user-agent basis. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-total-cache-and-wordpress-mobile-pack?replies=24#post-1493138

Answer (score 2):

Alex King's WordPress Mobile Edition plugin is my favorite:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/

Answer (score 1):

You site is probably already iphone/ipad/android friendly.

All those phones use native browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The most iPad-*unfriendly* thing you can do is try to cater for the device with a dedicated theme, especially if that theme is the OnSwipe one that WordPress favour. Please *do not* do this unless you actively want your iPad-using readers to hate you.

If your blog is WP-hosted, this will be enabled by default. *Please* go to your dashboard and turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend [WPTouch](http://www.bravenewcode.com/wptouch/) which now has great iPad support. There is a basic free version which EAMann mentioned but I would recommend the paid version which is only $39 and has a lot more features. You can then customize the look and feel.